Is there any way to detect .NET version in my custom C# compiler? (with Roslyn)
I want to build my own C# compiler (new csc) and I want to add features that detect .NET version (.NET 4.5 to .NET 8) but it only return fixed value (like "net5.0") this is my code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;

class CustomCsc
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 2 || args[0] != "build")
        {
            Console.Write("Usage: csc build <file>.cs\n\nThis compiler is provided as a part of new C#, but only supported from .NET 4.5 (C# 5) to .NET 8 (C# 12), for newer .NET versions, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240");
            return;
        }

        string filePath = args[1];
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"File '{filePath}' does not exist.");
            return;
        }
        CompileFile(filePath);
    }
    static string ReadTargetRuntimeFromCsproj(string filePath)
    {
        return "net5.0";
    }
    static bool IsSupportedRuntime(string targetRuntime)
    {
        return targetRuntime == "net5.0" || targetRuntime == "net6.0";
    }
    static void CompileFile(string filePath)
    {
        string code = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);

        // Modify syntax tree to support new keywords and syntax
        syntaxTree = ModifySyntaxTree(syntaxTree);

        MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
        {
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Console).Assembly.Location)
        };

        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath),
            new[] { syntaxTree },
            references,
            new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication));

        string outputPath = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".exe");
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in result.Diagnostics)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(diagnostic.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (var fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    ms.CopyTo(fs);
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Compilation succeeded: {outputPath}");
            }
        }
    }

    static SyntaxTree ModifySyntaxTree(SyntaxTree tree)
    {
        var rewriter = new CustomSyntaxRewriter();
        var root = rewriter.Visit(tree.GetRoot());
        return CSharpSyntaxTree.Create((CSharpSyntaxNode)root);
    }
}

class CustomSyntaxRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        // Handle 'and' and 'or'
        if (node.OperatorToken.IsKind(SyntaxKind.AmpersandAmpersandToken) && node.OperatorToken.Text == "and")
        {
            return node.WithOperatorToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.LogicalAndExpression));
        }

        if (node.OperatorToken.IsKind(SyntaxKind.BarBarToken) && node.OperatorToken.Text == "or")
        {
            return node.WithOperatorToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.LogicalOrExpression));
        }

        // Handle 'xor'
        if (node.OperatorToken.IsKind(SyntaxKind.CaretToken) && node.OperatorToken.Text == "xor")
        {
            return node.WithOperatorToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ExclusiveOrExpression));
        }

        return base.VisitBinaryExpression(node);
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitPrefixUnaryExpression(PrefixUnaryExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        // Handle 'not'
        if (node.OperatorToken.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ExclamationToken) && node.OperatorToken.Text == "not")
        {
            return node.WithOperatorToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.LogicalNotExpression));
        }

        return base.VisitPrefixUnaryExpression(node);
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitUsingDirective(UsingDirectiveSyntax node)
    {
        // Custom syntax modification to support 'using <b> as <a>;'
        if (node.Alias == null && node.Name is QualifiedNameSyntax qualifiedName && qualifiedName.Right is IdentifierNameSyntax asName)
        {
            var newAlias = SyntaxFactory.NameEquals(asName);
            var newUsing = node.WithAlias(newAlias).WithName(qualifiedName.Left);
            return newUsing;
        }

        return base.VisitUsingDirective(node);
    }
}

My questions:

Can have a way to read .csproj dynamically in .cs file?
Can change the fixed value to non-fixed value in this?
Information (all i can):


My .NET version now: 8
Visual Studio version: Visual Studio 2022 17.10.1
Windows version: Windows 11
New csc support version: .NET 4.5 (C# 5) to .NET 8 (C# 12)

I tried to find a way to read .csproj dynamically in this file .cs, but i can't find any ways for this problem

.csproj files are XML, so you can use XmlReader in System.Xml to get the InnerText property of TargetFramework or TargetFrameworkVersion tags

Reading the .csproj as XML might not give you reliable values. Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/evaluate-items-and-properties if you want reliable values.
